# How to get fileindex without using file handle?

Tags: c++, winapi

The function **GetFileInformationByHandle** gives us a structure with the values nFileIndexHigh and nFileIndexLow which comprise of a **fileIndex**.

What is this number? Is it the same as the USN?

Is there a way to get this **fileIndex** of a file **without opening it** (any other method except GetFileInformationByHandle)?

Comment: If you are feeling adventurous you could open the volume and parse the NTFS structures directly; short of that I think all the other methods require a file handle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [ZwQueryDirectoryFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff567047(VS.85).aspx) with `FileObjectIdInformation`, `FileIdBothDirectoryInformation`, `FileIdFullDirectoryInformation` to query for object ID information for the files in a directory. In the case you have to open only the directory having the file and not the file itself. It can be useful for example if the file is opened for exclusive access or of cause if you has no permission to open a file and not have or want not use backup privilege.

**UPDATED**: The following test example

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

typedef LONG NTSTATUS;
#define NT_SUCCESS(Status) (((NTSTATUS)(Status)) >= 0)
#define NT_STATUS(x)((NTSTATUS) { x })
#define STATUS_SUCCESS            ((NTSTATUS)0x00000000L)
#define STATUS_NO_MORE_FILES      ((NTSTATUS)0x80000006L)
#define STATUS_INVALID_INFO_CLASS ((NTSTATUS)0xC0000003L)

typedef struct _UNICODE_STRING
{
    USHORT Length;
    USHORT MaximumLength;
    PWSTR Buffer;
} UNICODE_STRING, *PUNICODE_STRING;

typedef struct _IO_STATUS_BLOCK {
    union {
        NTSTATUS Status;
        PVOID Pointer;
    } DUMMYUNIONNAME;

    ULONG_PTR Information;
} IO_STATUS_BLOCK, *PIO_STATUS_BLOCK;

typedef VOID (NTAPI *PIO_APC_ROUTINE) (PVOID ApcContext, PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock, ULONG Reserved);

typedef enum _FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS {
    FileDirectoryInformation         = 1,
    FileFullDirectoryInformation,   // 2
    FileBothDirectoryInformation,   // 3
    FileBasicInformation,           // 4
    FileStandardInformation,        // 5
    FileInternalInformation,        // 6
    FileEaInformation,              // 7
    FileAccessInformation,          // 8
    FileNameInformation,            // 9
    FileRenameInformation,          // 10
    FileLinkInformation,            // 11
    FileNamesInformation,           // 12
    FileDispositionInformation,     // 13
    FilePositionInformation,        // 14
    FileFullEaInformation,          // 15
    FileModeInformation,            // 16
    FileAlignmentInformation,       // 17
    FileAllInformation,             // 18
    FileAllocationInformation,      // 19
    FileEndOfFileInformation,       // 20
    FileAlternateNameInformation,   // 21
    FileStreamInformation,          // 22
    FilePipeInformation,            // 23
    FilePipeLocalInformation,       // 24
    FilePipeRemoteInformation,      // 25
    FileMailslotQueryInformation,   // 26
    FileMailslotSetInformation,     // 27
    FileCompressionInformation,     // 28
    FileObjectIdInformation,        // 29
    FileCompletionInformation,      // 30
    FileMoveClusterInformation,     // 31
    FileQuotaInformation,           // 32
    FileReparsePointInformation,    // 33
    FileNetworkOpenInformation,     // 34
    FileAttributeTagInformation,    // 35
    FileTrackingInformation,        // 36
    FileIdBothDirectoryInformation, // 37
    FileIdFullDirectoryInformation, // 38
    FileValidDataLengthInformation, // 39
    FileShortNameInformation,       // 40
    FileIoCompletionNotificationInformation, // 41
    FileIoStatusBlockRangeInformation,       // 42
    FileIoPriorityHintInformation,           // 43
    FileSfioReserveInformation,              // 44
    FileSfioVolumeInformation,               // 45
    FileHardLinkInformation,                 // 46
    FileProcessIdsUsingFileInformation,      // 47
    FileNormalizedNameInformation,           // 48
    FileNetworkPhysicalNameInformation,      // 49
    FileIdGlobalTxDirectoryInformation,      // 50
    FileIsRemoteDeviceInformation,           // 51
    FileAttributeCacheInformation,           // 52
    FileNumaNodeInformation,                 // 53
    FileStandardLinkInformation,             // 54
    FileRemoteProtocolInformation,           // 55
    FileMaximumInformation
} FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS, *PFILE_INFORMATION_CLASS;

typedef struct _FILE_ID_FULL_DIR_INFORMATION {
    ULONG NextEntryOffset;
    ULONG FileIndex;
    LARGE_INTEGER CreationTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER LastAccessTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER LastWriteTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER ChangeTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER EndOfFile;
    LARGE_INTEGER AllocationSize;
    ULONG FileAttributes;
    ULONG FileNameLength;
    ULONG EaSize;
    LARGE_INTEGER FileId;
    WCHAR FileName[1];
} FILE_ID_FULL_DIR_INFORMATION, *PFILE_ID_FULL_DIR_INFORMATION;

typedef struct _FILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION {
    ULONG NextEntryOffset;
    ULONG FileIndex;
    LARGE_INTEGER CreationTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER LastAccessTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER LastWriteTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER ChangeTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER EndOfFile;
    LARGE_INTEGER AllocationSize;
    ULONG FileAttributes;
    ULONG FileNameLength;
    ULONG EaSize;
    CCHAR ShortNameLength;
    WCHAR ShortName[12];
    LARGE_INTEGER FileId;
    WCHAR FileName[1];
} FILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION, *PFILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION;

typedef struct _FILE_ID_GLOBAL_TX_DIR_INFORMATION {
    ULONG NextEntryOffset;
    ULONG FileIndex;
    LARGE_INTEGER CreationTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER LastAccessTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER LastWriteTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER ChangeTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER EndOfFile;
    LARGE_INTEGER AllocationSize;
    ULONG FileAttributes;
    ULONG FileNameLength;
    LARGE_INTEGER FileId;
    GUID LockingTransactionId;
    ULONG TxInfoFlags;
    WCHAR FileName[1];
} FILE_ID_GLOBAL_TX_DIR_INFORMATION, *PFILE_ID_GLOBAL_TX_DIR_INFORMATION;

#define FILE_ID_GLOBAL_TX_DIR_INFO_FLAG_WRITELOCKED         0x00000001
#define FILE_ID_GLOBAL_TX_DIR_INFO_FLAG_VISIBLE_TO_TX       0x00000002
#define FILE_ID_GLOBAL_TX_DIR_INFO_FLAG_VISIBLE_OUTSIDE_TX  0x00000004

typedef struct _FILE_OBJECTID_INFORMATION {
    LONGLONG FileReference;
    UCHAR ObjectId[16];
    union {
        struct {
            UCHAR BirthVolumeId[16];
            UCHAR BirthObjectId[16];
            UCHAR DomainId[16];
        } DUMMYSTRUCTNAME;
        UCHAR ExtendedInfo[48];
    } DUMMYUNIONNAME;
} FILE_OBJECTID_INFORMATION, *PFILE_OBJECTID_INFORMATION;

typedef NTSTATUS (WINAPI *PZW_QUERY_DIRECTORY_FILE) (HANDLE FileHandle,
    HANDLE Event, PIO_APC_ROUTINE ApcRoutine, PVOID ApcContext, PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock,
    PVOID FileInformation, ULONG Length, FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS FileInformationClass,
    BOOLEAN ReturnSingleEntry, PUNICODE_STRING FileName, BOOLEAN RestartScan);

void DumpFileInformation (LPCWSTR pszDirName, LPCWSTR pszFileName)
{
    WCHAR szFileName[32767];
    UNICODE_STRING fn;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;
    NTSTATUS status;
    LONGLONG byBuffer[(32767+sizeof(FILE_ID_FULL_DIR_INFORMATION))/sizeof(LONGLONG)];
    PFILE_ID_FULL_DIR_INFORMATION pFullInfo = (PFILE_ID_FULL_DIR_INFORMATION)byBuffer;
    //PFILE_ID_GLOBAL_TX_DIR_INFORMATION pGlobalTxDirInfo = (PFILE_ID_GLOBAL_TX_DIR_INFORMATION)byBuffer;
    HANDLE hDir = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    PZW_QUERY_DIRECTORY_FILE ZwQueryDirectoryFile = (PZW_QUERY_DIRECTORY_FILE)
        GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll.dll"),"ZwQueryDirectoryFile");

    __try {
        hDir = CreateFileW (pszDirName, FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL,
                            OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL);
        if (hDir == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            _tprintf(TEXT("Can't open directory '%ls': Error %d\n"), pszDirName, GetLastError());
            __leave;
        }

        lstrcpyW (szFileName, pszFileName);
        fn.Buffer = (LPWSTR) szFileName;
        fn.Length = lstrlen(szFileName)*sizeof(WCHAR);
        fn.MaximumLength = sizeof(szFileName);
        RtlZeroMemory ((PVOID)&iosb, sizeof(iosb));
        status =  ZwQueryDirectoryFile (hDir, NULL, NULL, NULL, &iosb, byBuffer, sizeof(byBuffer),
                                        FileIdFullDirectoryInformation, TRUE, &fn, FALSE);
        if (NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            _tprintf (TEXT("The file '%ls%ls%ls' has FileId: 0x%08X%08X\n"),
                pszDirName,
                fn.Length>0 && pszDirName[fn.Length/sizeof(WCHAR)-1] == L'\\' ? L"": L"\\",
                szFileName,
                pFullInfo->FileId.HighPart, pFullInfo->FileId.LowPart);
        }
    }
    __finally {
        if (hDir != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            CloseHandle (hDir);
    }
}

int _tmain ()
{
    DumpFileInformation (L"C:\\", L"System Volume Information");
    DumpFileInformation (L"C:\\", L"pagefile.sys");
    return 0;
}
```

produce on my computer as the output:

```
The file 'C:\\System Volume Information' has FileId: 0x000100000000A2F0
The file 'C:\\pagefile.sys' has FileId: 0x006B00000000A673
```

Comment: I used it to get the id of a simple file: DumpFileInformation (L"C:\\temp\\", L"Printerlist.txt"); and applied the GetFileInformationByHandle on the same file and they both returned the same id! The msdn entries are so misleading, I wonder why...

Answer (score 2):

according to the MSDN page for the [BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363788%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), the fileIndex is:

> The identifier (low and high parts)
>   and the volume serial number uniquely
>   identify a file on a single computer.
>   To determine whether two open handles
>   represent the same file, combine the
>   identifier and the volume serial
>   number for each file and compare them.

And

> The identifier that is stored in the
>   nFileIndexHigh and nFileIndexLow
>   members is called the file ID. Support
>   for file IDs is file system-specific.
>   File IDs are not guaranteed to be
>   unique over time, because file systems
>   are free to reuse them. In some cases,
>   the file ID for a file can change over
>   time.

However it seems this is the only way to get the info, short of the internal kernel functions, which are probably going to need a handle too

Answer (score 1):

There is example code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866454/unique-file-identifier-in-windows) on how to get this in two different ways. Both require a handle though...

The Windows docs suggest this can be gotten without a handle (but with much work) using [FltQueryInformationFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff543439(v=VS.85).aspx). Even here the file must be open, so somebody is going to have a handle to it.