# An example to get last access time of file in java using jdk1.7

Tags: java

Friends please help. I know that using jdk1.7 we can get the last access time of file. Can anyone give an example with codes to get last access time of file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the last access time for a file in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920259/getting-the-last-access-time-for-a-file-in-java)

Comment: I've read the above mentioned post.But it did not consist of an example to do the same.

Comment: Or, for Windows OS, you can also use JNA to get the last accessed time information of a file via `GetFileInformationByHandle()` function. [Get unique file id in Windows with Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309199/get-unique-file-id-in-windows-with-java)

Comment: @Rak, have you tried this new thing? It’s called “programming.”

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you mentioned in your question using **jdk1.7** , you should really look into the interface BasicFileAttributes on method [lastAccessTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html#lastAccessTime%28%29) . I'm not sure what is your real question but if you mean you want an example with codes on reading a file last access time using jdk7, take a look at below.

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.nio.file.Files;

/** 
 * compile using jdk1.7
 *
 */
public class ReadFileLastAccess {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Path file_dir = Paths.get("/home/user/");
        Path file = file_dir.resolve("testfile.txt");
        BasicFileAttributes attrs = Files.readAttributes(file, BasicFileAttributes.class);       
        System.out.println("Last accessed at:" + attrs.lastAccessTime());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code snippet that return last access time:

```
public Date getLastAccessTime(String filePath) throws IOException {
    File f = new File(filePath);
    BasicFileAttributes basicFileAttributes = Files.getFileAttributeView(f.toPath(), BasicFileAttributeView.class).readAttributes();
    Date accessTime = new Date(basicFileAttributes.lastAccessTime().toMillis());
    return accessTime;
}
```

I have tested it on JDK 1.7.0 Developer Preview on MacOS X.

Comment: i see that the method getFileAttributeView(f.toPath(), BasicFileAttributeView.class) asks for 3 parameters. why is this difference there ?

Comment: @randeepsp: The last one is varargs

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar example using compiler version 1.7 (Java 7)

```
import java.nio.file.Files; 
import java.nio.file.Path; 
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes; 

class E 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    { 
        // On Dos (Windows) File system path
        Path p = Paths.get( "C:\\a\\b\\Log.txt"); 

        BasicFileAttributes bfa = Files.readAttributes(p, BasicFileAttributes.class); 

        System.out.println(bfa.lastModifiedTime()); 
    } 
}
```