# How to get the latest downloaded filename in Java or using any commands on Windows platform?

Tags: java, command-line

My requirement is to get the latest downloaded file from the given path.
In My Project am downloading a file to "Downloads" folder, then I need to open the same edit and upload. I was able to download the file progrmmatically, Pls suggest how can i get the file name using Java or any Commands which can be implemented in Java.

am using Windows 7 OS

Comment: So, to put things more clearly, you need to know the most recently created file in a given directory, right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File contains lastModified().

```
    File uploadDirectory = new File("your_download_directory");
    File[] downloadedFiles = uploadDirectory.listFiles();

    Arrays.sort(downloadedFiles, new Comparator<File>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(File fileOne, File fileTwo) {
            return Long.valueOf(fileOne.lastModified()).compareTo(fileTwo.lastModified());
        }
    });

    for (File file : downloadedFiles) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            // upload file
        }
    }
```

Comment: I need to get the name of the lastest downloaded file in the directory.. From the above code I was able to get the list of downlaoded files

Comment: Yes, you get a list of all files sorted by date. Get the top one and get the name or anything else on the instance. For example file.getName().

Comment: thanks for the reply, iwas able to meet tmy requirement.

Answer (score 1):

This is only possible in Java >= 7.

Look at BasicFileAttributes.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html

Also check out these links.

[An example to get last access time of file in java using jdk1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082357/an-example-to-get-last-access-time-of-file-in-java-using-jdk1-7)

[Get the Last Access Time for a File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920259/getting-the-last-access-time-for-a-file-in-java)

--- UPDATE BEGIN ---

To get all files in a folder use:

```
String dirName = "some-name";
File dir = new File(dirName);
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
```

See also:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29

--- UPDATE END ---

Comment: I need to get the name of the lastest downloaded file in hte directory.. From the above links am unable to get the same.

Comment: @user1787641 Get all the files but sort them by their creationTime, this was my point. What do you expect - to find a built-in method getLastCreatedFile in the API?

Comment: I can sort based on the creation time, but how can i get the file name?? ya something similar to getLastCreatedFile().