# Unique File Identifier

Tags: c#, .net, file, unique, identifier

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unique file identifier in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866454/unique-file-identifier-in-windows)

I need to retrieve a unique identifier for certain files on the computer, and have only came across the Win32 GetFileInformationByHandle function. How can I accomplish this with the. NET framework?

Update: I need a persistent id that will not change if the file is moved, updated, renamed, etc.

Update2: How can the same be accomplished with folders?

Comment: The path to the file isn't unique enough?

Comment: If you explain what "unique identifier" you mean it may be possible to answer... So far looks like good candidate for close.

Comment: I need a persistent uid, moving the file will alter the path of course.

Comment: What about creating a SHA hash of the contents PLUS the full path name? That should be unique enough, although it's not clear what it is you want to do here.

Comment: @kprobst - That isn't any better than either of the solutions alone. Then if the file changed _or_ it was moved it'll invalidate the id.

Comment: if the file is moved and the content changed it is not really the same file anymore. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Please loook at the question update, I need an id that will not change if something is renamed, moved, updated, etc

Comment: That's easy... there isn't such an ID.

Comment: @BrokenGlass from the user's perspective, it is still the same file.

Comment: Then add a mapping layer that makes it appear that way *for the user*. What you are looking for doesn't exist on a file system level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some code from [Ashley Henderson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5023/ashley-henderson) I copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1866788/635634). It implies two approaches which both return the same unique identifier.

```
public class WinAPI
    {
        [DllImport("ntdll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr NtQueryInformationFile(IntPtr fileHandle, ref IO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock, IntPtr pInfoBlock, uint length, FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS fileInformation);

        public struct IO_STATUS_BLOCK
        {
            uint status;
            ulong information;
        }
        public struct _FILE_INTERNAL_INFORMATION {
          public ulong  IndexNumber;
        } 

        // Abbreviated, there are more values than shown
        public enum FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS
        {
            FileDirectoryInformation = 1,     // 1
            FileFullDirectoryInformation,     // 2
            FileBothDirectoryInformation,     // 3
            FileBasicInformation,         // 4
            FileStandardInformation,      // 5
            FileInternalInformation      // 6
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool GetFileInformationByHandle(IntPtr hFile,out BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION lpFileInformation);

        public struct BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION
        {
            public uint FileAttributes;
            public FILETIME CreationTime;
            public FILETIME LastAccessTime;
            public FILETIME LastWriteTime;
            public uint VolumeSerialNumber;
            public uint FileSizeHigh;
            public uint FileSizeLow;
            public uint NumberOfLinks;
            public uint FileIndexHigh;
            public uint FileIndexLow;
        }
  }

  public class Test
  {
       public ulong ApproachA()
       {
                WinAPI.IO_STATUS_BLOCK iostatus=new WinAPI.IO_STATUS_BLOCK();

                WinAPI._FILE_INTERNAL_INFORMATION objectIDInfo = new WinAPI._FILE_INTERNAL_INFORMATION();

                int structSize = Marshal.SizeOf(objectIDInfo);

                FileInfo fi=new FileInfo(@"C:\Temp\testfile.txt");
                FileStream fs=fi.Open(FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read,FileShare.ReadWrite);

                IntPtr res=WinAPI.NtQueryInformationFile(fs.Handle, ref iostatus, memPtr, (uint)structSize, WinAPI.FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS.FileInternalInformation);

                objectIDInfo = (WinAPI._FILE_INTERNAL_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(memPtr, typeof(WinAPI._FILE_INTERNAL_INFORMATION));

                fs.Close();

                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(memPtr);   

                return objectIDInfo.IndexNumber;

       }

       public ulong ApproachB()
       {
               WinAPI.BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION objectFileInfo=new WinAPI.BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION();

                FileInfo fi=new FileInfo(@"C:\Temp\testfile.txt");
                FileStream fs=fi.Open(FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read,FileShare.ReadWrite);

                WinAPI.GetFileInformationByHandle(fs.Handle, out objectFileInfo);

                fs.Close();

                ulong fileIndex = ((ulong)objectFileInfo.FileIndexHigh << 32) + (ulong)objectFileInfo.FileIndexLow;

                return fileIndex;   
       }
  }
```

Comment: Be sure to read the comment on the answer regarding a known shortcoming.

Comment: @ebeeb, this method works great, thanks! How can i accomplish the same with folders?

Comment: @ebeeb http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132686/unique-folder-identifier

Answer (score 1):

I assume the file format isn't under your control (otherwise, generatea UUID and store it there).

**File Object ID's**

NTFS supports object ID's on the file level, see [FSCTL_CREATE_OR_GET_OBJECT_ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364393%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I haven't used them to be able to recommend them, but it seems like a promising thing to explore.

As with alternate data streams (below), they can get lost when copying to a non-NTFS-medium ("usual" memory sticks, CD's, DVD's, flash cards, possibly even some USB disks. ...). Also, some applications might mess up when they recreate the file when saving.

**Distributed Link Tracking Service**

[Distributed Link Tracking Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363997%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) uses file object ID's for, well, tracking links to files, and repairing them when the file is moved.

AFAIK Distributed Link Tracking Service requires a domain controller for the server. Again, I have no practical experience with this.

**On NTFS, you could also create and store a UUID in an [alternate data stream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Alternate_data_streams_.28ADS.29).**

Caveats:

- Only available on NTFS, will not "survive" on other file systems
- One white paper "the future of NTFS" considered killing them, but I fancy the thought there were some other features that could help you (unfortunately, I failed to dig that out)
- I wouldn't want to create that for thousands of files of unknown origin and purpose. Though they "just work" on the file system level, some applications might mess up.

**Some document formats - such as Office - allow [custom document properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e0tda25%28VS.80%29.aspx).**

That's obviously limited, but similar mechanisms can be piggybacked onto other file types as well. (e.g. many image formats would allow adding / rewriting "custom" chunks that should be ignored by readers)

**FileFromID vs. IDFromFile**

Alll solutions except DLTS only allow `IDFromFile` lookup, i.e. locating a file that has moved (or was deleted) requires searching all potential drives.

For DLTS, if there's no "direct API" way, you could store a DLTS-enabled shortcut in an application-specific folder, and ~~hope for~~ expect the service to repair the shortcut when the file is moved.

Comment: Bear in mind ADS is also what viruses use so their values are closely scrutinized by Antivirus like software (sometimes destructively).

Answer (score -1):

You can get the MD5 hash for the files, take this example:

```
string GetMD5HashFromFile(string fileName)
{
    FileStream file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
    MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] retVal = md5.ComputeHash(file);
    file.Close();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < retVal.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(retVal[i].ToString("x2"));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

this will return a unique identifier for each file.

Comment: Won't this change if the file's contents change?

Comment: if the file is updated, the hash will change

Comment: of course, it will depends of what are your needs, please add more information on your question

Comment: md5 is not guaranteed unique, however you are looking at a 16^32 chance of it being replicated. However is you want unique then md5 is not your answer, however it WILL provide a reproducible key for each file meaning a hash of a file will match a rehash of the same file but this is not the same as being unique.