# Unique Folder Identifier

Tags: c#, .net, directory, unique, identifier

Earlier today someone generously answered my question regarding the retrieval of a unique identifier associated with files on the computer. [Unique File Identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129623/unique-file-identifier)

The solution worked great, however, it does not address unique identifiers for folders. How can I retrieve a UID for specified directories, UID's that will stay with the directory through renames and moves.

Update: FSCTL_GET_OBJECT_ID seems like it is the function I am after, but would someone be able to provide brief context on the usage? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that's what you need - those are assignable object ID-s. As per this link [2.4.20 FileInternalInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc232072(v=prot.13).aspx) it says `by the file system and is unique to the volume on which the file or directory is located` (btw. that's the same thing, just from C++ perspective more, there is only one 'ID' for file/dir). Anyway, identifiers should not discriminate directories in any way, as you can move them alike etc. I'm not putting this as an answer - but I think it actually is. What's actually 'not working'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put this into an answer, because it was too much text for a comment.

I answered your question regarding *Unique File Identifiers*. I didn't dig in too deep into this topic. That's been just good [researching skills](http://www.google.de/).

I researched a bit and collected some documentation links that may help you:

- [Local File Systems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364407%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [CSIDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [KNOWNFOLDERID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Known Folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I've been searching for quite a time, but I couldn't find anything which identifies **each** folder, regardless of its path.

The only folders, which always can be identified - as far as I know, yet - are these **known folders**. That's because one WinOS uses the *C:/winnt/Windows Net/* and another one uses *D:/Windows/Net/* path (don't look up those, I just made them up off the top of my head).

Comment: I suppose you havnt found anything to solve folder id:s since this was written?