# HANDLE (IntPtr) Obsolete, kernel32.dll, SafeFileHandle to IntPtr

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll

I am in need of implementing  a solution very similar to the one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1866788/3469725), written in 2009, to retrieve a unique identifier for a file. Specifically, I am looking at the answer's `ApproachB()` function and the following line (re-written a bit to reflect new C# capabilities):

```
var fi = new FileInfo(@"C:\Temp\testfile.txt");
var fs = fi.Open(FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read,FileShare.ReadWrite);
WinAPI.GetFileInformationByHandle(fs.Handle, out objectFileInfo); // fs.Handle being the portion in question
```

The problem, here, is that [GetFileInformationByHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364952(v=vs.85).aspx) maps to an `extern` function imported from the "kernel32.dll". The signature of which is as follows:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool GetFileInformationByHandle(IntPtr hFile, out BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION lpFileInformation);
```

Type `IntPtr` maps well to the specified type in the above linked doc.s `HANDLE`. However, the `Handle` property on `FileStream` objects has been deprecated (made [obsolete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.handle(v=vs.100).aspx)) and replaced with `SafeFileHandle` which *does not* map to a `IntPtr`.

Is there a way to overcome this to where the `extern` definition can accept the type `SafeFileHandle`? Or, is there another `extern` method that has been implemented for this purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your PInvoke signature to

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool GetFileInformationByHandle(SafeFileHandle hFile, out BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION lpFileInformation);
```

or keep it and call on your SafeFileHandle instance the method .DangerousGetHandle() which will return the IntPtr you are searching for. This method is implemented in the base class SafeHandle which is made for exactly that purpose.