# FileSystemWatcher not raising when files are copied or moved to folder

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting moved files using FileSystemWatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286114/detecting-moved-files-using-filesystemwatcher)

I was looking for a solution to watch a directory and notify my app whenever a new file is moved into the directory. The Obvious solution was to use FileSystemWatcher class of the .NET.

But the problem is , it raises a event a new file is created/deleted in the folder but does not raises event when a file is moved/copied into the folder.

Can anyone tell me what could be the cause of such behavior.

my code is

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Run();
    }

    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public static void Run()
    {
        // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = @"D:\New folder";
        /* Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
           the renaming of files or directories. */
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
           | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
        // Only watch text files.
        watcher.Filter = "*.txt";

        // Add event handlers.
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

        // Begin watching.
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        // Wait for the user to quit the program.
        Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the sample.");
        while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;
    }

    // Define the event handlers.
    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
        Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
    }

    private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is renamed.
        Console.WriteLine("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);
    }
```

Comment: Your code looks amazingly similar to MSDN code! https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.renamed(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used FileSystemWatcher in one of my Home application. But FileSystemWatcher do not have any move or copy detection events as per my knowledge.

As per MSDN

> **Copying and moving folders**
>
> The operating system and FileSystemWatcher object interpret a
>   cut-and-paste action or a move action as a rename action for a folder
>   and its contents. If you cut and paste a folder with files into a
>   folder being watched, the FileSystemWatcher object reports only the
>   folder as new, but not its contents because they are essentially only
>   renamed.

For more information click [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx).

What I did was monitoring the parent folder and sub folders and logged every changes in it.
To include sub directories I used the following property.

```
watcher.IncludeSubdirectories=true;
```

Some googling suggesting to use timer to detect changes. But I don't know how effective it is.